# Oracle - Why Is Querying Date Column in View So Slow (Compared to Table)?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have an Oracle table with several date columns.  There is no explicit index on the individual date columns, but they do participate in a composite key.  When I perform a query against any of these date columns in the base table - querying is very fast (sub-second).

I then have a simple view which joins to only one other table.  The SQL for that view is at the end of this post.  When I query against the date columns (MONTHID or HOURID) is this view - performance is awful - so I am sure a full table scan is happening.  If I query against any other column in this view - performance is great.  I am just wondering why the difference.  I have tried all types of shenanigans with using hints and the like with no luck.

Please help.

```
  SELECT CHN_SLOC_HOUR_FACT.UTILITYID,
    chn_sloc_hour_fact.MONTHID,
    chn_sloc_hour_fact.hourid,
    CHN_SLOC_HOUR_FACT.METERID,
    CHN_SLOC_HOUR_FACT.CH_V_AVG_A_MIN,
    CHN_SLOC_HOUR_FACT.CH_V_AVG_A_MAX,
    CHN_SLOC_HOUR_FACT.CH_V_AVG_A_AVG,
    SERVICELOCATION.GEOMETRY
  FROM CHN_SLOC_HOUR_FACT
  INNER JOIN SERVICELOCATION
  ON SERVICELOCATION.ID = CHN_SLOC_HOUR_FACT.SERVICE_LOCATION_ID;
```

**UPDATE:**

Base Table Query

Query SQL:

```
select * 
from chn_sloc_hour_fact 
where utilityid = 6 
  and monthid = to_date('01-Mar-14','DD-MON-YY') 
  and hourid = to_date('03-Mar-14 12:00:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Plan Table Output

```
Plan hash value: 2202514416

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                          | Name                   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                   |                        | 12298 |    12M| 13709   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID| CHN_SLOC_HOUR_FACT     | 12298 |    12M| 13709   (1)| 00:00:01 | ROWID | ROWID |
|*  2 |   INDEX SKIP SCAN                  | CHN_SLOC_HOUR_FACT_UK1 |    26 |       | 13361   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("UTILITYID"=6)
   2 - access("MONTHID"=TO_DATE('01-Mar-14','DD-MON-YY') AND "HOURID"=TO_DATE('03-Mar-14 12:00:00','DD-MON-YY 
              HH24:MI:SS'))
       filter("HOURID"=TO_DATE('03-Mar-14 12:00:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS') AND 
              "MONTHID"=TO_DATE('01-Mar-14','DD-MON-YY'))
```

View Query:

Query SQL:

```
select * 
from gis_servicelocation_hour_dist 
where utilityid = 6 
  and monthid = to_date('01-Mar-14','DD-MON-YY') 
  and hourid = to_date('03-Mar-14 12:00:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Plan Table Output

```
Plan hash value: 245188272

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name                   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |                        | 12298 |  2810K| 13904   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN                          |                        | 12298 |  2810K| 13904   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID| CHN_SLOC_HOUR_FACT     | 12298 |   540K| 13709   (1)| 00:00:01 | ROWID | ROWID |
|*  3 |    INDEX SKIP SCAN                  | CHN_SLOC_HOUR_FACT_UK1 |    26 |       | 13361   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   4 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL                 | SERVICELOCATION        | 35123 |  6482K|   195   (2)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("SERVICELOCATION"."ID"="CHN_SLOC_HOUR_FACT"."SERVICE_LOCATION_ID")
   2 - filter("CHN_SLOC_HOUR_FACT"."UTILITYID"=6)
   3 - access("CHN_SLOC_HOUR_FACT"."MONTHID"=TO_DATE('01-Mar-14','DD-MON-YY') AND 
              "CHN_SLOC_HOUR_FACT"."HOURID"=TO_DATE('03-Mar-14 12:00:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'))
       filter("CHN_SLOC_HOUR_FACT"."HOURID"=TO_DATE('03-Mar-14 12:00:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS') AND 
              "CHN_SLOC_HOUR_FACT"."MONTHID"=TO_DATE('01-Mar-14','DD-MON-YY'))
```

Comment: Please show us the execution plan for the slow and the fast query (as formatted plain text please, no pictures)

Comment: Those two statements are not doing the same thing. The first one only selects from `chn_sloc_hour_fact` while the view includes the `SERVICELOCATION` table. As you are doing a `select *` Oracle cannot remove the `servicelocation` from the query (and the full table scan is what is hurting you there). Try to explicitly select only the columns that come from the  `chn_sloc_hour_fact` table. Maybe the optimizer is then smart enough to remove `servivcelocation` from the query plan.

Comment: Horse is correct, or you could add the stuff you need to your index.